# Gson and Retrofit got an error : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, rest, gson, retrofit2

I'm new using Retrofit and Gson, and I'm facing an error as below when I try to send request to REST API using POST method.

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 4 column 14 path $.data

Below is my java code.

```
private void sendRequest(CheckEmail checkEmail){
    ApiInterface apiService =  ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<CheckEmail> call = apiService.getEmailStatus(checkEmail);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CheckEmail>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CheckEmail> call, Response<CheckEmail> response) {

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            CheckEmail checkEmail = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response.body().getData()), CheckEmail.class);
            Toast.makeText(CheckEmailPage.this, "Successfull "+checkEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CheckEmail> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CheckEmailPage.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Error Retrofit : ", String.valueOf(t));

        }
    });

}
```

Below is my model

```
public class CheckEmail {

private int code;
private String message;
private String[] data;

public CheckEmail(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String[] getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

this is my class that initialize the URL and retrofit builder

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://f49d9d29-8471-4126-95b0-1ec3d18eda94.mock.pstmn.io/v1/";
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getClient(){

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

and below is ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@POST("users/check_status")
Call<CheckEmail> getEmailStatus(@Body CheckEmail email);
}
```

this is my json response that I was hit from postman

```
{
"code": 1000,
"message": "OK",
"data": {
    "id": "1",
    "email": "test.test@gmail.com",
    "status": "1",
    "name": "testing",
    "category": "2"
}
```

}

whats wrong with my code ?
thankyou in advance

Comment: post your real response please !! that the server is giving

Comment: `private String[] data;` instead of array you are getting an object may be ..so you can wrap `private String[] data;` in an object !! ( **my guess** )

Comment: this is very common when your response is an object, but you modeled it as an array. We'd need to look into your json response

Comment: the response type is Response<CheckEmail>, why you are parsing again using Gson builder. it is already  parsed. just use response.body.getData() and save it to String[] data.

Comment: I've been add json response to my question. and I've been save it into String[] data before, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The response (i.e. Response<> response) already parsed. no need to parse it again using `gson builder`. just fetch data from response like below :

```
String data[] = response.body().getData();
```

No need to use gson builder here :

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder(); // remove this code
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();// remove this code

CheckEmail checkEmail = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response.body().getData()), CheckEmail.class);// remove this code
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, I've been using your way, but the error still occurs.

Comment: do you have the json which is coming from server?

Answer (score 0):

data in your checkEmail class is not a string array.

replace data with the following class instead.

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private String category;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getCategory() {
return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
this.category = category;
}

}
```

your checkEmail class should be something like the following (String[] is replaced by the Data class)

```
public class CheckEmail{

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

public Integer getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
this.code = code;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public Data getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```